# Modular document with many bibliographies: unique identifier for each chapter?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I've searched this stackexchange and the wider world wide web for an answer to this question to no avail, so I thought I'd try my luck asking. Basically, I would like a unique identifier for each chapters bibliography. Explanation below.

Like many other questions that have been asked, I am compiling a PhD thesis as a modular document and each chapter has its own bibliography.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}
    \usepackage[sectionbib, square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
    \begin{document}
    <<Title page, acknowledgements etc>>

    \include{Chapters/Introduction}
    \include{Chapters/Chapter1}
    \include{Chapters/Chapter2}
    \include{Chapters/Conclusions}

    \end{document}
```

Thats the main file, and each chapter/conclusions/intro etc has the format:

```
  \chapter{Chapter title} 

  Text

  \label{Bibliography}
  \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
  \bibliography{bibtexfile.bib}
```

And the bibtexfiles are just usual .bib files with @articles @books @misc etc, all of these are ripped off journal websites.

As it stands, every single chapter has it's own Bibliography section and these are numbered 1-Whatever in the correct order which I love. I was told in my PhD defence to either compile one massive bibliography at the end of the thesis (which I hate) OR keep the individual chapter bibs but have each of them a unique identifier. The example chosen was that if I open a page and see reference number 33, which bibliography should I go to for ref 33?

Is there a way to have each bibliography list the references with a chapter-specific identifier. For example, chapter 3 references 20 might be listed as [3-20] in the text? Or something similar..

any help is appreciated, I included what I believe to  be all the relevant code but if anything is unclear please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It might be useful to mention *which* `Thesis` document class you are using.

Comment: Ahoy hoy, the thesis template was downloaded from here http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

original author Steve Gunn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!

Keeping everything in the question identical, but instead of

```
\usepackage[sectionbib, square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
```

use:

```
\usepackage{cite} \renewcommand\citeform{\thechapter.}
```

The last argument there detailing how you want the prefix to act. For a modular document, you can change each citation form per chapter. For example, I have an un-numbered Introduction and then Chapters 1-5. The bibliography in the Introduction can be labelled I.23 (for ref 23..) by using 
    \usepackage{cite} \renewcommand\citeform{I.}